# Angular mat-table Sticky Column overlaps when Scrolled

Tags: angular, sticky, mat-table

I'm using Angular 8's table (not using flex) with first 2 columns as sticky.

Issue :

1. The main issue is the space between the 1st and 2nd columns which leads to other issues.
2. When I do a horizontal scroll, the scrolling data is visible in the space between those columns
3. There is a css property which sets left to be 159px. How is this calculated?

Reproducing the issue.

Use Angular's table example with sticky columns. https://stackblitz.com/angular/lynkxvonedv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.html

1. Add Sticky to the 2nd column (Position)
2. Add a long text to any non-sticky column. (I have used it for Weight column).

[image: ScreenShot]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround which may help you.

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.pipe(take(3)).subscribe(() => this.table.updateStickyColumnStyles());
}
```

GitHub Link: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15885

Comment: let me try this out.. By the way what does this code do ??

Comment: @josiebhai - onMicrotaskEmpty event is fired when there is no microtasks are enqueued in the current VM. So whenever all microtasks are completed `this.table.updateStickyColumnStyles()` will be called to re calculate the sticky position. And `this.table` you have to do a query using @ViewChild().

Answer (score 2):

For me mat table was inside a *ngIf condition so I have to do something like below.

```
@ViewChild('matTable', { static: false }) set table(matTable: MatTable<any>) {
    if (matTable) {
      this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty
        .pipe(take(3))
        .subscribe(() => matTable.updateStickyColumnStyles())
    }
  }
```